# Conditionally Select Rows within a Group with Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for solutions using data.table ― I have a data.table with the following columns:

```
data <- data.frame(GROUP=c(3,3,4,4,5,6),
                    YEAR=c(1979,1985,1999,2011,2012,1994),
                    NAME=c("S","A","J","L","G","A"))

data <- as.data.table(data)
```

Data.table:

```
GROUP  YEAR    NAME
3      1979    Smith 
3      1985    Anderson
4      1999    James
4      2011    Liam
5      2012    George
6      1994    Adams
```

For each group we want to select one row using the following rule:

- If there is a year > 2000, select the row with minimum year **above** 2000.
- If there not a year > 2000, select the row with the maximum year.

Desired output:

```
GROUP  YEAR    NAME
3      1985    Anderson
4      2011    Liam
5      2012    George
6      1994    Adams
```

Thanks! I have been struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data.table` should be a lot simpler if you subset the special `.I` row counter:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[
  data[
        ,
        if(any(YEAR > 2000)) 
           .I[which.min(2000 - YEAR)] else
           .I[which.max(YEAR)],
        by=GROUP
      ]$V1
]
#   GROUP YEAR NAME
#1:     3 1985    A
#2:     4 2011    L
#3:     5 2012    G
#4:     6 1994    A
```

Thanks to @r2evans for the background info -

> `.I` is an integer vector equivalent to `seq_len(nrow(x))`.
>    Ref:
>   http://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/special-symbols.html

So, all I'm doing here is getting the matching row index for the whole of `data` for each of the calculations at each `by=` level. Then using these row indexes to subset `data` again.

Comment: I get an error `Error in [.data.frame(data, , if (any(YEAR > 2000)) .I[which.min(2000 -  : 
  unused argument (by = GROUP)` Does it work exactly as is for you?

Comment: @user10626943 - the post is tagged `data.table` so I assumed OP was already working with a `data.table` - if not, you need to convert first. Have edited.

Comment: For late-comers, `.I` is an integer vector equivalent to `seq_len(nrow(x))`. Ref: https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/special-symbols.html (I had to look it up :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could also do a couple rolling joins:

```
res = unique(data[, .(GROUP)])

# get row with YEAR above 2000
res[, w := data[c(.SD, YEAR = 2000), on=.(GROUP, YEAR), roll=-Inf, which=TRUE]]

# if none found, get row with nearest YEAR below   
res[is.na(w), w := data[c(.SD, YEAR = 2000), on=.(GROUP, YEAR), roll=Inf, which=TRUE]]

# subset by row numbers
data[res$w]

   GROUP YEAR NAME
1:     3 1985    A
2:     4 2011    L
3:     5 2012    G
4:     6 1994    A
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `dplyr` package I got your output like this (though it may not be the simplest answer):

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(magrittr)

 data <- data.frame(GROUP=c(3,3,4,4,5,6),
                    YEAR=c(1979,1985,1999,2011,2012,1994),
                    NAME=c("S","A","J","L","G","A"))

 data %>%
   subset(YEAR < 2000) %>%
   group_by(GROUP) %>%
   summarise(MAX=max(YEAR)) %>%
   join(data %>%
          subset(YEAR > 2000) %>%
          group_by(GROUP) %>%
          summarise(MIN=min(YEAR)), type="full") %>%
   mutate(YEAR=ifelse(is.na(MIN), MAX, MIN)) %>%
   select(c(GROUP, YEAR)) %>%
   join(data)
```

Results:

```
   GROUP YEAR NAME
      3  1985   A
      4  2011   L
      5  2012   G
      6  1994   A
```

EDIT: Sorry, my first answer didn't take into account the min/max conditions. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tidyverse solution! and for the formatting pointers.